# How to merge Users on Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I have imported our SVN repository into Mercurial and now we have entries for the same user that don't match.

e,g, for me I have

Sam Mackrill
smackrill
SMackrill

is there are way to merge these into one user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What tools do you use for importing? If it was `hg convert` or *hgsubversion* extension, then you can re-import your data providing an up-to-date authors file, that handles various names for the same person. See the `--authors` option of those Mercurial commands.

Comment: The documentation for `hg convert` implies that you can "convert" your Mercurial repository to Mercurial while specifying a new username mapping file, thus avoiding reimporting from Subversion.